# remove TD with empty attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table><tr>
<td class="delete" new="1">1</td>
<td class="delete" new="2">2</td>
<td class="delete" new="">3</td>
<td class="delete" new="5">4</td>
<td class="delete" new="6">5</td>
</tr>
</table>

$('.delete').remove();
```

how can i remove TD with attribute **new=""** (null)?

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/xhvMd/

Comment: jQuery has good documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.delete[new=""]').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the custom attributes in jquery like this

```
$('.delete[new=1]').remove();
```

Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tNFaB/)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="delete" new="1">
            1
        </td>
        <td class="delete" new="2">
            2
        </td>
        <td class="delete" new="">
            3
        </td>
        <td class="delete" new="5">
            4
        </td>
        <td class="delete" new="6">
            5
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.delete[new=""]').remove();
</script>
```